# Preventing state change of ui-router displaying back button in next state in ionic

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, ionic-framework

I am using the below code to prevent the state change in ui-router.

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', 
      function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){ 
          event.preventDefault(); 
 });
```

but again if I move to any state it displays ionic back button enable.

As per my knowledge it is adding to the ionicHistory but couldn't find any solution.

Help with the solution please.

Comment: can you be more elaborate on what you are trying to achieve ?

Comment: I am trying to display a prompt confirmation before navigating to  another state so i am listening to stateChangeStart and event.preventDefault() does the trick here but when on confirmation i again route then on next view ionic back button is showing enable.